# Importing Telegram API from GitHub repository to Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, telegram, telegram-bot

As you know Telegram API is open on GitHub. I tried to import it on my Android Studio. My android studio is up to date and also SDK is updated till the date. I have generated signed APK and tried to run project and got following errors. I have chosen x86 based to compile and tried to run it.

`Screenshot.`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/32S1N.png

```
05/23 21:39:23: Launching TMessagesProj
The currently selected variant "arm-debug" uses split APKs, but none of the 1 split apks are compatible with the current device with density "560" and ABIs "x86".
Error while Installing APK
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: *The currently selected variant "arm-debug"* means you need an ARM image, not an x86 image

Answer (score 2):

The following image describes the solution. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

in the defaultConfig (gradle Build file) add this at the end of android {} check for your architectures

```
android {
  ...
  splits {
    abi {
      enable true
      reset()
      include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips'
      universalApk true
    }
  }
}
```